# Retrofit Body is Sometimes Null

Tags: android, retrofit

It may be only happening when working with LAN, but I am getting a null body in the response on occasion. Checking the same request in browser or a REST client shows a body, and the Content-Length is not zero (It's actually 12,504, that's plenty more than zero) Any ideas?

Comment: Try to be more specific, post some of the controller code and the erroneous request possibly. It sounds like a backend problem something is returning null instead of the expected i think.

Comment: Do you have any code to provide on how you are making the request?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the exception wasn't coming through (I do know if you pause then jump into a catch, the exception object will almost always be null) but it was my fault - the API had changed and GSON was expecting a String where an Object was being returned.